# JFileChooser Translation

Tags: java, localization, translation, jfilechooser

I need to translate **completely** JFileChooser form. I'm mannaged to get all the keys except:

- the "Go up" of the contextual menu when you right click a file name.
- the description that appears when hovering with the mouse over the desktop icon

Anyone has the name of these keys?

Just in case, here is the list of all the other keys:

```
"FileChooser.lookInLabelText",
"FileChooser.lookInLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.fileNameLabelText",
"FileChooser.fileNameLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText",
"FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText",
"FileChooser.upFolderAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText",
"FileChooser.homeFolderAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText",
"FileChooser.newFolderAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText",
"FileChooser.listViewButtonAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText",
"FileChooser.detailsViewButtonAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.cancelButtonText",
"FileChooser.cancelButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText",
"FileChooser.openButtonText",
"FileChooser.openButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText",
"FileChooser.saveButtonText",
"FileChooser.saveButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.saveButtonToolTipText",
"FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText",
"FileChooser.openDialogTitleText",
"FileChooser.saveDialogTitleText",
"FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText",
"FileChooser.newFolderAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.viewMenuLabelText",
"FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText",
"FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText",
"FileChooser.goupFolderActionLabelText",
"FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText",
"FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText",
"FileChooser.foldersLabelText",
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm kind of late to answer this question, but anyone who's still looking for manual translation keys:

```
"FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText",
"FileChooser.ancestorInputMap",
"FileChooser.byDateText",
"FileChooser.byNameText",
"FileChooser.cancelButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.cancelButtonText",
"FileChooser.chooseButtonText",
"FileChooser.createButtonText",
"FileChooser.desktopName",
"FileChooser.detailsViewIcon",
"FileChooser.directoryDescriptionText",
"FileChooser.directoryOpenButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.directoryOpenButtonText",
"FileChooser.fileDescriptionText",
"FileChooser.fileNameLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.fileNameLabelText",
"FileChooser.fileSizeGigaBytes",
"FileChooser.fileSizeKiloBytes",
"FileChooser.fileSizeMegaBytes",
"FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText",
"FileChooser.helpButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.helpButtonText",
"FileChooser.homeFolderIcon",
"FileChooser.listViewIcon",
"FileChooser.lookInLabelMnemonic",
"FileChooser.mac.newFolder",
"FileChooser.mac.newFolder.subsequent",
"FileChooser.newFolderAccessibleName",
"FileChooser.newFolderButtonText",
"FileChooser.newFolderErrorSeparator",
"FileChooser.newFolderErrorText",
"FileChooser.newFolderExistsErrorText",
"FileChooser.newFolderIcon",
"FileChooser.newFolderPromptText",
"FileChooser.newFolderTitleText",
"FileChooser.openButtonMnemonic"
"FileChooser.openButtonText",
"FileChooser.openDialogTitleText",
"FileChooser.openTitleText",
"FileChooser.readOnly",
"FileChooser.saveButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.saveButtonText",
"FileChooser.saveDialogFileNameLabelText",
"FileChooser.saveDialogTitleText",
"FileChooser.saveTitleText",
"FileChooser.untitledFileName",
"FileChooser.untitledFolderName",
"FileChooser.upFolderIcon",
"FileChooser.updateButtonMnemonic",
"FileChooser.updateButtonText",
"FileChooser.useSystemExtensionHiding",
"FileChooser.usesSingleFilePane"
```

Here is the [Source](https://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/)

Answer (score 0):

FileChooser.viewMenuButtonToolTipText missed

Answer (score -1):

Can't you change the [locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) if it's available for the language you want?

Otherwise, you can look into [internationalization](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/internationalization-for-swing-standard-components/).

Comment: The language I want is Portuguese and Spanish. No locales defined for these 2.

Comment: Probably too late for @AlexandreGoncalves, but for future SO'ers there are most definitely Locales for Portuguese and Spanish in Java. There just aren't *static constants* for those locales. new Locale("pt") and new Locale("es") will give Portuguese and Spanish -- country and variants can be added to the constructors as well.